# Inbox showing wrong number of answers

Tags: support, bug

I asked a question today [Should I offer to refund an upfront payment for a job I failed to complete?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/815/should-i-offer-refund-of-upfront-payment-of-a-job-i-failed-to-complete/817?noredirect=1#817) at Freelancing.SE. It has received 2 answers so far. But in inbox it shows 4 answers. I am not sure why it is showing 4 instead of 2. I think it is due to some bug. I have also attached  screenshot of my inbox.

[image]

Comment: Yup, bug. I'll flag a dev when I'm on my computer

Comment: I just want to note that, at this moment in time, there are still only 3 posted answers, 0 deleted answers.

Comment: @jmort253 Yes, at the time of posting there were 2 posted answers and inbox was saying 4 answers. But now, there are 3 answers and inbox is also saying 3 answers.

Comment: Then it seems your glitch isn't active at the moment. Anyway, I just wanted to emphasize and clarify your point that there never were 4 answers... not even ones that were deleted. Hope this helps!